# Failed to access Tomcat started by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

i installed and setup `tomcat 7` locally, started it from command line below,

```
$ startup.sh
```

-> successfully gained the access to http://localhost:8080

```
$ shutdown.sh
```

Next i started it from `eclipse 3.7` below,

```
Servers -> Tomcat 7 -> start
```

Console output:

```
....
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Server startup in 1234 ms
```

-> however, failed to access http://localhost:8080

```
HTTP Status 404 - /
type Status report
message /
description The requested resource (/) is not available.
```

Did i miss anything to bind `tomcat 7` to `eclipse 3.7`?

**@EDIT**

According to `@magomi` suggestion, i created a simple `dynamic web project` from `eclipse 3.7`, then ran it together with `tomcat 7` successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is running but no ROOT application is installed. When you start tomcat right from your IDE only the specified application will be deployed. So you have to access this application via `http://localhost:8080/<yourapp>`.